# Can't toggle the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[[Fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/8cg4f/666/)

In the example, I'm trying to make each pair of buttons toggle the text by matching data attributes. I can change the text from "Add" to "Remove on click. But I can't toggle it back to "Add" on second click. Can anyone tell me what's the problem?

HTML:

```
<div class="yellow"><button class="my_choice" data-term="A">Remove</button>
<button class="my_choice" data-term="A">Remove</button>
</div>
<div class="black">
<button class="my_choice" data-term="B">Add</button>

<button class="my_choice" data-term="B">Add</button>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.my_choice').click(function(){
      var dataterm = $(this).data('term'),
          my_choice = $('.my_choice[data-term='+dataterm+']')
      if (my_choice.text() == "Remove")
      {
          my_choice.text("Add")
      }
      else
      {
          my_choice.text("Remove")
      }

});
```

Comment: try debugging, print to console to see where the error is.

Comment: your question always enters else loop thats why add an alert before if loop and you will find out why this is happening

Comment: FYI: The jquery you posted doesn't match the jquery in your fiddle.  You have the conditional reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting text using class selector so its returning text of all elements with class **my_choice** which is in this case **addadd** instead of **add** and for remove case **removeremove** instead of **remove** so use `$(this).text()` to get current clicked one text.

so you have to do like this:

```
$('.my_choice').click(function(){
    var text= $(this).text();
      var dataterm = $(this).data('term'),

          my_choice = $('.my_choice[data-term='+dataterm+']')
      console.log(my_choice.text())
      if (text == "Remove")
      {
          my_choice.text("Add")
      }
      else
      {
          my_choice.text("Remove")
      }

});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8qJcr/)

Comment: +1 for adding an explanation why the current code didn't work instead of just showing code that works.

Answer (score 3):

Just change the conditional to reference the clicked item, not the all the matching buttons

```
if (my_choice.text() == "Remove")
```

to:

```
if ($(this).text() == "Remove")
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8cg4f/668/)

As you have it, you're trying to read the `text()` from multiple buttons, which is why it's not working.  You need to limit the `text()` to read from just one button.

Edit:

Updated my answer to reference the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8cg4f/673/)

As i earlier pointed out your code always entered else case

```
$('.my_choice').click(function(){
      var dataterm = $(this).data('term'),


      if ($(this).text() === "Remove")//change only applied in your code and added some semi colon 
      {
          my_choice.text("Add");

      }
      else
      {
          my_choice.text("Remove");
      }

});
```